# Add Menu Folders Ubuntu Studio 19.10

Tags: xfce, 19.10, menu, ubuntu-studio, xfce-panel

I am trying to add a new subfolder to Ubuntu Studio 19.10 as I am a lighting designer as well and have some lighting specific apps that I will be installing on to my system.

I have no issue adding apps to the system, but they seem to be put in whatever category they feel like. I want to create a Submenu / Category for Lighting design and move the Apps into it.

I've tried LibreMenu, Alacarte and I don't seem to be able to create SubMenus/Categories. Apps seem to be Ok though. I seem to just break the menu.

I've even tried making a `Lighting.desktop` file and `ubuntustudio-lighting.desktop` file but they don't even appear in my menu.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I might achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

We created Ubuntu Studio Menu Item Editor (ubuntustudio-menu-add) just for this purpose, though it is in very early stages. The goal is to not mess with the default menus like alacarte or libremenu have a tendency to do. I will admit that it's not super intuitive, but it does the job.